# How can i create a startup script with sles 11?

Tags: linux, startup-scripts, sles11

I have a problem in one of my servers. I have a SLES 11 server and I have bond (bond0) two ethernet cards (eth0 and eth1). 
i setup mtu to be 9000 on all interfaces. When i reboot the server the mtu change to the default value 1500 and i have to run manually the command ifconfig ethA mtu 9000 up to all the interfaces.

I want to create a script that will run everytime the system reboots.

It is normally not my job to write init-scripts, since I expect the system to behave "right". In this case I set MTU in `yast2`to 9000 but it does not work.

Comment: Yes - I came across that on SLES11 SP3 as well. You have to solve this with an own init-script indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify `/etc/init.d/boot.local` to add what you want.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your quick response. I make the necessary changes at boot.local but when i reboot the server i had the same situation.
I run the command who -r and i saw that i run at level 5. Do you know if i have to copy the specific file into rc.5d?

Comment: It should work without doing that. Try using "sudo" with the command as well.

Comment: So inside the boot.local i will run only the following? 
sudo -u root ifconfig eth0 mtu 9000
sudo -u root ifconfig eth1 mtu 9000
sudo -u root ifconfig bond0 mtu 9000

Comment: Correct. If that doesn't work, there's also an `after.local` that runs after everything else has started. You'll have to create this file in the same init.d folder.

Comment: Do you know how to create that file? Sorry if i bother you but i have stuck three days about that.